# How to extend web.searchUtils class in odoo15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I want to make small changes to `web/static/src/legacy/js/control_panel/search_utils.js` file (i have commented my changes). But unfortunately, I can't find an example of how to do it. There is a constant defined in this module and I want to override it to add two extra months to the filtering.

How to patch or extend this?

```
odoo.define('web.searchUtils', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    ...

    const MONTH_OPTIONS = {
        // ↓↓↓ my update
        following_month: {
            id: 'following_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: +2 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
        next_month: {
            id: 'next_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: +1 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
        // ↑↑↑ my update
        this_month: {
            id: 'this_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: {}, granularity: 'month',
        },
        last_month: {
            id: 'last_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: -1 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
        antepenultimate_month: {
            id: 'antepenultimate_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: -2 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
    };

    ...

});
```

UPDATED!
i've tried this ↓ solution, but it doesn't work

```
odoo.define('tada.searchUtils', function(require) {
    "use strict";
    
    var searchUtils = require('web.searchUtils');
    
    searchUtils.MONTH_OPTIONS = {
        following_month: {
            id: 'following_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: +2 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
        next_month: {
            id: 'next_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: +1 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
        this_month: {
            id: 'this_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: {}, granularity: 'month',
        },
        last_month: {
            id: 'last_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: -1 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
        antepenultimate_month: {
            id: 'antepenultimate_month', groupNumber: 1, format: 'MMMM',
            addParam: { months: -2 }, granularity: 'month',
        },
    };

});
```